# Values does not get inserted, but commit is happening

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
offer = Offer.first
  Offer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "offers".* FROM "offers" ORDER BY "offers"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Offer id: 1, name: "goa trip", description: "2 days", vendor_id: 1, created_at: "2016-10-12 08:57:14", updated_at: "2016-10-12 08:57:14"> 
2.2.3 :014 > offer.coupons.create(coupon_code: "1245343")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Coupon id: nil, coupon_code: "1245343", offer_id: 1, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.2.3 :015 > Coupon.all
  Coupon Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "coupons".* FROM "coupons"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Here are the relationships in model wise

```
class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :offers
end

class Offer < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :coupons
  belongs_to :vendor
end

class Coupon < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :offer
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is the schema

```
create_table "vendors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "company_name"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end
create_table "offers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "vendor_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.index ["vendor_id"], name: "index_offers_on_vendor_id"
  end

create_table "coupons", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "coupon_code"
    t.integer  "offer_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.index ["offer_id"], name: "index_coupons_on_offer_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_coupons_on_user_id"
  end
```

Also please let me know if I am using the relationships in a wrong manner. Thanks

Comment: `offer.coupons.create!(coupon_code: "1245343")` will tell you why it's not being saved

Comment: Validation failed User must exist is the error I have got. Is this new in rails 5? But I can update the user only later .. once it is redeemed. Should I look into middle table? Can you help me out?

Comment: if you want to create coupon without `user_id` and edit `user_id` later remove the index in a new migration. `rails g migration remove_index_from_coupons` and in created file `remove_index :coupons, : index_coupons_on_user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running

```
offer.coupons.create!(coupon_code: "1245343")
```

will reveal the validation errors.

My assumption is that you have to specify `user_id` as well, since you're having and index `index_coupons_on_user_id`.

In Rails 5 - when referencing a model, index on the foreign_key is automatically created.

You have 2 foreign_keys:

- `offer_id`
- `user_id`

Thus, two indices are created.

Comment: I am still getting the same validation error. My schema is this 

 ```create_table "coupons", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "coupon_code"
    t.integer  "offer_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.index ["offer_id"], name: "index_coupons_on_offer_id"
  end```

Comment: @gates just out of curiosity: what if you comment the line `belongs_to :user`?

Comment: @gates yea, In Rails 5 - when we reference a model (in your case `user_id` and `offer_id`), index on the foreign_key is automatically created.

Comment: I think that is cool in some way that u don't have to manually create index .. but u can get stumble upon these edge cases